# Convert Java to C# - ParseObject

Tags: parse-platform

I have not seen any example that resolves my issue retrieving data. Here is the Java code:

```
String sender = msgObj.getParseObject("sender").getString("firstname");
```

This works for me in C#:

```
msgObj.Get<string>("message")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check structure of the sender in the java code. It is an object and probably has properties such as firstname, lastname amoung others. You will need to create a similar class in C# and then type cast the sender object from the msgObj and finally get it's properties. The code would be something like this;

```
mySenderClass senderObj = msgObj.Get<mySenderClass>("sender");
string first_name = senderObject.Get<string>("firstname");
```

Comment: It turns out I needed to pass the correct type. Due to the lack of samples in the Parse-SDK documentation, I had to step thru the objects and figure out what I needed.

So, I discovered that accessing the properties from my Java sample, this is what I had to do:

    var user = msgObj.Get<ParseUser>("sender");

Just as you mentioned mySenderClass is ParseUser in this case.

So, thank you for helping me get the resolution.